# return value if mysql query returns no results

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I am trying to make it so that if the input username exists to fetch the details for that username, and if no username exists to tell me so...

So far it will tell me if the username exists, but not if it does not exist...

So basically if the query returns zero results how do I get it to say "hey there were no matches" ?

my code so far...

```
$user = $_POST['txtUsername'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `weaponstreat` WHERE username='$user'";
$rows = $db->query($sql); while ($record = $db->fetch_array($rows)) {

    if ($record['tid'] === NULL) { echo "empty"; } else { echo "full"; }
}
```

Comment: check my answer below, simply add a variable which will be incremented in while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$user = $_POST['txtUsername'];
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) rcount FROM `weaponstreat` WHERE username='$user'";
$rows = $db->query($sql); while ($record = $db->fetch_array($rows)) {

    if ($record['rcount'] == 0) { echo "empty"; } else { echo "full"; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check to see if any rows are returned:

```
if ($db->num_rows() == 0)
{
    // No results
 }
else
{
    while ($record = $db->fetch_array($rows)) {
        if ($record['tid'] === NULL) { echo "empty"; } else { echo "full"; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = $_POST['txtUsername'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `weaponstreat` WHERE username='$user'";
$rows = $db->query($sql);
// add a counter variable 
$counterRecords = 0;
while ($record = $db->fetch_array($rows)) {

    $counterRecords++;
}

if($counterRecords==0)
 echo "empty";
else echo "full";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = $_POST['txtUsername'];

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM weaponstreat WHERE username='$user' ORDER BY tid DESC");

if ( mysql_num_rows( $query ) > 0 )
{
    // Process and display username details
}
else
{
    echo "That username does not exist";
}
```